# Logging instance information in Exceptions

Tags: exceptions, logging, exception-handling

During development on a large existing codebase I've started to capture variable values in my Exception logging. For example:

```
public int Foo(int a, int b)
{
   int returnInt;
   try{
      returnInt = bar(a) * b;
   }
   catch (Exception ex){
      ex.Message += "a: {0}, b: {1}", a, b;
      logger.log(ex);
   }

   return returnInt;
}
```

While I'm not asking about this specific pseudocode I wondered if there were any valid reasons to not do this?

To me it would seem that logging instance variables in addition to the more general error message and stack trace is a positive thing. However I've never seen it done elsewhere.

Comment: My first thought is that, if you're not careful, you risk causing yet another exception within your catch block.

Comment: This, as far as I can see, is the only real problem with the approach of logging these variables. Given a compiled language like C# you're not at risk of having invalid value parameters passed in. Logging those seems safe enough, with reference types creating a new exception is a risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, exceptions are to deal with "exceptional/unexpected" behavior of your application. If you want to log information, you should use a proper logging framework.

It's also much cleaner to see something like

```
...
} catch (Exception ex){
      logger.error(String.format("something went wrong with information %s %s", "infoA", "infoB"));
      throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the situation where you're using something like NLog or the Enterprise library (for C#) for error logging you can call a method like ```Logger.Log(Exception ex)```. I agree the code example as presented in my question is bad code (I deliberately avoided String.Format to make the code sample invalid/pseudocode/not specifically C#). 

To me having the variables in the exception message ties them together making the job of the guy reading the log easier, but I can see how it's worse for proper error handling.

Comment: I'm actually a Java developer but the idea I was trying to pass is to separate the concerns. Logging deals with logging and Exceptions deal with unexpected behavior.

Comment: Is it not standard to log exceptions (e.g. ELMAH database logging for C#) however? And if you're logging the exception shouldn't you log instance information about what makes it exceptional?

Comment: Sorry I should probably clarify, this is logging that is not presented to the end user, just internal logs used for support.

Comment: Sure you can add a log.error(ex.getMessage()); or something. Usually, I write my own business exceptions and let the framework to take care of logging the exceptions. And yes, I'm only considering this as system logging. For the client side, it would prob have a try/catch block to catch the exception and display a friendly message to fellow user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a security expert, but the only reason I can think of would be for security.

It may NOT be a good idea to log the variables when the values contains sensitive or personal user's information.  For example the user's name, address, SSN, credit card, etc...  I would try to log the transaction id or order id as a reference whenever possible.

Another situation would be the table definition or a SQL statement, which would disclose your architecture and design.

Sometimes it's hard not to implement some of these when they are the key value in determining the problem, so I think, it's a balance between support and security.

Answer (score 0):

I take the "log anything and everything"* approach to logging because otherwise the one thing that you don't log will inevitably be the thing that you need to know when the exception occurs.

*of course as Bri points out I avoid logging passwords, (some) personal details, and payment details. Some personal information may be useful to log (name and email address) to help identify the person and potentially contact them about the error that occurred but there may be legal issues with this depending on your location.